# React Slick slider map not showing slides?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js

I am facing the following problem, where the React Slick slider is not displaying my slides inside the map function. Tried multiple things, but keep getting empty values.

When i hardcode divs it works, but when i try to create them dynamic even when the exist the don't show up.

Can someone help?

My code:

```
  <Slider {...settings}>
    {this.props.home.fetched &&
      this.props.home.content.map(value => {
        return value.acf.slider_extends.map((value, index) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <h1>{value.project_titel}</h1>
              <p>{value.project_intro}</p>
              <span>{value.video_project}</span>
            </div>
          );
        });
      })}
  </Slider>
```

Comment: you're missing the `key` attribute to the `div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Slider from 'react-slick';

class Home extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            sliders: [
                'http://img.nowrunning.com/content/movie/2014/Jagga-Jaso/wall_1024x768_01.jpg',
                'https://alchetron.com/cdn/Cocktail-2012-film-images-6dbd0ec2-2ea4-47aa-88fd-388cabed7f8.jpg',
                'http://media.glamsham.com/download/wallpaper/movies/images/z/zindagi-na-milegi-dobara-wallpaper-03-12x9.jpg']
        }
    }

    sliders() {
        return this.state.sliders.map(data => {
            return (
                <div key={data}>
                    <img alt="image" src={data} />
                </div>
            )
        });
    }

    render() {
        const settings = {
            dots: true,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 4000,
            arrow: false
        }
        return (
            <div >
                <Slider {...settings}>
                    {this.sliders()}
                </Slider>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 3):

If the containing div or section of Slick has the property flex, than it can cause pictures to disappear.